Issue with Accounts Not Displaying in Remix VM (Cancun and Shanghai) Environments
I'm encountering an issue with Remix VM where, after successful compilation, the accounts are not displaying in the "Deploy" section. This problem persists in both the Cancun and Shanghai environments. I've attempted to use two different browsers, Brave and Chrome, but the issue remains.
Steps I've taken to troubleshoot include refreshing the page, switching between different environments, and then reverting back to Cancun and Shanghai, but none of these steps have resolved the issue. Due to this, I'm unable to deploy any contracts.
Has anyone else experienced this problem? If so, how were you able to resolve it?

This problem is with crome i guess , change chrome profile it will work

I have had this problem when connecting to localhost using remixd.
I am able to compile and deploy my contract when I set my compile target and then deploy environment to Paris, however not when I set my compile target and then my deploy environment to Cancan or Shanghai.
I am able work around this by setting up a blank workspace and uploading my folder containing the contract.
I am then able to compile and deploy my contract to Cancan or Shanghai.
